# send html email with php contains special characters

Tags: php, email, utf-8, special-characters

i need to send php email with html and special characters like è, à, ò .." and i've write this:

```
$message = "
        <html>
            <head>
            <title>TITLE</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              &#224 &#232
            </body>
        </html>";

$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;  charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: NoReply <noreply@asd.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: NoReply <noreply@asd.com>\r\n";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Now, when i launch my script, on gmail preview of received email is correct (letters are showed correctly), but when i open email, i see " &#224 &#232", not the relative special character. How can i solve it (without using external libraries)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use utf8_decode() function for $message.

```
$message = "<html>
               <head>
                   <title>TITLE</title>
               </head>
               <body>
                  &#224; &#232;
               </body>
            </html>";

mail($email, $subject, utf8_decode($message), $headers);
```

Comment: You have to use proper html entities. You are missing semi-colon(;) at the end. There is syntax error. Use &#224;

Answer (score 0):

In order to use special characters in your script you can try [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) function.